# Plotting two variables based on a value from another column using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working with a dataset that has a few columns, such as Continent, economic status, and literacy rate. I'm looking for a way to plot a scatterplot on based on the economic status and literacy rate in Asian Countries:

```
economy <- data$Economic status
literacy <- data$literacy rate

ggplot(data = subset(data, Continent == 'Asian countries'), aes(x = economy, y = literacy)) +
  geom_point()
```

But I keep getting an error message that the Aesthetics are not the same lengths as the data. I'm just not sure if I have to somehow trim the data by continent before using that code, or somehow change the economy/literacy variables to be only from Asian countries within the code.

thank you!

Comment: Reproducible example, please.

Comment: You should post a reproducible example, but by just reading your question it seems like what you want to use is [facets](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data = subset...` term is telling ggplot that you want to use a shorter version of `data` using only the rows where the Continent is Asia. Then your `aes` mapping is referring to vectors that are the length of the original data (including all Continents). `ggplot` needs these to have the same length; the fact they're not is a sign they are not referring to the same data.

I presume something like this should work:

```
ggplot(data = subset(data, Continent == 'Asian countries'),  
  aes(x =`Economic status`, y = `literacy rate`)) +  
  geom_point()
```